# How to find the true and false by matching the elements in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like a and b.
a is reference array for matching with b
needs to do count where:
array a element value 0 is matches the element value 0 in array b as true and
array a elemet value 0 is matches with element value 1 in array b as true

```
a=np.array([[0,0,1,1,1],
            [1,0,1,1,1],
            [1,1,0,1,0],
            [0,1,1,0,1]])

b=np.array([[1,0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,0,1,0],
            [1,0,0,1,1],
            [0,1,0,1,0]])
```

EXpected output is like :

```
[[True,True,False,False,False],
[False,True,False,False,False],
[False,False,True,False,True],
[True,False,False,True,False]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `a==0 & b==0` -> `True` OR `a==0 & b==1` -> `True`, else `False`, then the value of b doesn't matter (assuming you only have 0/1 as values).

You just want `a==0`:

```
a==0
```

or

```
~a.astype(bool)
```

output:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False]])
```

If `b` can contain values other that 0/1, then use:

```
a==0 & np.isin(b, [0,1])
```